# how to fix responsive background image?

Tags: css, background

i need a responsive background image that will scale and keep its aspect ratio when resized within its container, anybody have any suggestions. This is what i been working on for 3 days, everything works great but the container takes up alot of space, and if i mess with the height it will mess up the aspect ratio.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2 class="heading">Responsive Background CSS</h2>

    <div class="container"> 
        <a href="#" class="image">Background Image Applied Here</a>
    </div>

    <section class="about"></section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.cf:before, .cf:after, {
    display: table;
    content:"";
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.heading {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    min-height:1px;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color:orange;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.image {
    background:url(img/image%201.jpg);
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 177.7777777777778%;
    height: 0;
    background-size: 100% !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.about {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color:tomato;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: More important, where is your CSS.

Comment: Add CSS, also try the backgound-size contain/cover properties.

Comment: im trying to, im new here lol

Answer (score 0):

You can try this custom plugin made for `responsive images`(`background`)

http://webonise.github.io/jQuery-plugins/fullScreenImage/responsive-full-screen.html

Answer (score 0):

You could always just change the image depending on the screen size. You'd want to use the same image, just different sizes. This way you can crop the images in ways that better display your intentions for the background image.

[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/lihidalu/1/). Change the browser size to see the changes.